# id's generated and used in two places: possible?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I try to generate the epub 3.0 .opf file automatically, using an index.xml that describes the build-up of that file. 
The general construction of the .opf looks like this:

```
<package>
   <metadata>
     ....
   </metadata>
   <manifest>
      <item id="a1" href="uniquefilename1.xml" media-type="m1"   /> 
       --- and lots more of items.
   </manifest>  
   <spine>
      <itemref idref="a1">
      ---- and lots more of itemref's
      </itemref>
   </spine>
 </package>
```

I left out a lot of detail.

The idref's refer back to the items. The id's of the items, I "generate-id()". I would like to generate the idrefs from those id's, in the same transformation.
Not all item's get referred to in spine, but those that are, are recognizable in manifest by their media-type (=m1).
So when constructing spine, I would need a tree containing the finished manifest, and be able to refer to the items and their id.
I suppose I could build manifest in a variable. But can I scan that variable later on to find id's to use in spine?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. In general, generate-id() generates an id for the nodes of the **input** XML document.

Comment: Is `a1` a string defined in the stylesheet or did you mean a node from the source document (`{a1}`)??

Comment: both a1 would be generated during execution of the templates. First the item and its id, then, when it's id is generated, I would build itemref and "pick up" the earlier generated id of item, eg. via a variable.

Comment: I think you still need to add more detail. If you have more than one **item**, then, when you come to generate an **itemref** how do you know which **item** to get the @id for? It would probably help if you showed a small, but representative sample of your input XML, and the output you expect to be generated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML to XML - Create Unique IDs and reference them in the same document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611567/xml-to-xml-create-unique-ids-and-reference-them-in-the-same-document)